# Changing route programmatically with two different props types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im already passing in props to this component, the interface works well with location: any. But now I want to also want to pass in `props:RouteComponentProps` so I can programmatically change views. the error I get is..

`Type '(props: RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<propsInterface>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'PropsWithChildren<propsInterface>' is missing the following properties from type 'RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>': history, matchts(2322`

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface propsInterface {
  location: any; 
}

const Home: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props:RouteComponentProps) => {
     props.history.push('/myOtherPage')
```

Comment: You are saying your component props is of type `propsInterface` but then you type it as `RouteComponentProps`. surely your component should look like: `const Home: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props:propsInterface)`

Comment: if your component wants to accept some more props you can either define them in your `propsInterface` or if you are sure you will implement entire interface you can extend some other interface e.g. `interface propsInterface extends RouteComponentProps`.

Comment: yes I want to be able to access props.location and props.history, how do I define this in interface?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can prepare your props in a component to accept the `RouteChildrenProps` props.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouteChildrenProps } from 'react-router';

export interface IProps extends RouteChildrenProps {}

const Results: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps): JSX.Element => (
   <>
    <p>{props.history.length}</p>
    <p>{props.location.search}</p>
    <p>{props.match && props.match.url}</p>
  </>
);

export default Results;
```

Then in your Router you can pass those values:

```
    <ConnectedRouter history={props.history} context={props.context}>

          <Route key={`${path}`} exact={exact} path={path}>
            {({ match, location, history }): JSX.Element => (

                  <Results
                    match={match}
                    history={history}
                    location={location}
                  />
            )}
          </Route>
    </ConnectedRouter>
```